# Div is unexpectedly shorter than page width when using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get the h1 heading "Title" to align in the center of the page, but for some reason the div is not as wide as the page itself. I am using Bootstrap css and Angular. Why isnt the blue div named maincontent the entire page width?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
</head>
<body id="page-top">
  <!-- Header -->
    <div id="maincontent">  
          <h1 class="name text-center" style="align-content:center">Title</h1>
          <hr class="star-light text-center">
          <span class="skills">x -- x -- x</span>
    </div>
 .....
```

[image]

Bootstrap was imported by adding it to angular.json:

```
"styles": [
    "src/my-theme.scss",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "src/app/dragndrop/dragndrop.js"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem must be in some other part of your CSS. When I test your html on a clean bootstrap CDN it works just fine, The title is centered. Take the snippet below and start from there. Add one other stylesheet at a time and identify and fix which is causing the div to not be full width.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 class="name text-center">Title</h1>
        <hr class="star-light text-center">
        <span class="skills">x -- x -- x</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```